# How do i use enum?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums

The enum i created in a new class this class is in a dll(library project) i have two projects in this solution the first dll(library) and the second windows forms:

The enum i created and want to use is DannysCommands:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace Capture.Interface
{
    public enum DannysCommands
    {
        Displayoverlays,
        Dontdisplayoverlays
    }

    public enum Direct3DVersion
    {
        Unknown,
        AutoDetect,
        Direct3D9,
        Direct3D10,
        Direct3D10_1,
        Direct3D11,
        Direct3D11_1,
    }

    [Serializable]
    public delegate void RecordingStartedEvent(CaptureConfig config);
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void RecordingStoppedEvent();
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void MessageReceivedEvent(MessageReceivedEventArgs message);
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void ScreenshotReceivedEvent(ScreenshotReceivedEventArgs response);
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void DisconnectedEvent();
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void ScreenshotRequestedEvent(ScreenshotRequest request);
    [Serializable]
    public delegate void DisplayTextEvent(DisplayTextEventArgs args);

    public enum MessageType
    {
        Debug,
        Information,
        Warning,
        Error
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class CaptureInterface : MarshalByRefObject
    {
```

Then in the same project there are two lines that draw and i want to make that when it's Displayoverlays draw and when it's Dontdisplayoverlays don't draw.

This class also i can call from form1 from project windows forms.
In form1 i want to use a button click and to check maybe with a bool variable so when it's Displayoverlays draw make the lines and when it's Dontdisplayoverlays don't draw.

In the dll(library) project there is another class with the drawing lines:

```
if (Capture.Interface.DannysCommands.Displayoverlays)
                            {

                            }     
                                _spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y, textElement.Text, textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
                                _spriteEngine.DrawString(textElement.Location.X + 1800, textElement.Location.Y + 25,
                                                  DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"), textElement.Color.R, textElement.Color.G, textElement.Color.B, textElement.Color.A, font);
```

I know the enum is not bool so this IF i did is not working give error.

How do i use the enum withing form1 and in the class with the draw lines ?

In form1 i want to make that when i click on a button once draw make the lines to draw second click on the button don't draw using the enum.

Answer (score 2):

Actually is not necessary to use Enum. From what i understand you need to draw the lines only once. Lets say you have a form:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    private bool isClicked;
    private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isClicked = false;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isClicked) return;
        isClicked = true;
        //...draw lines here...
    }
}
```

Enum is for when you have options and you want to give a standard set of choices to the programmers in order to limit the input and the of course the errors for unwanted input.

Enum you can use it with `switch` statement.

Comment: You are essentially tracking state with a bool. Which may be too simple for the OPs need (without seeing the full code, understanding the ubiquitous language, we cant know). There are many situations where the complexity and readability of the code is greatly enhanced by the use of enums.

Comment: I don't thing you can track state with enums either. In any case i don't have visibility to the full code to be able to suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a variable of type `DannysCommands`. You can work with that variable and check it's value in an if statement like you normally would.
So :
    DannysCommands cmd = DannysCommands.InitialValue;

At some point, you will do `cmd = DannysCommands.DisplayOverlays;`

And then:

```
if(cmd == DannysCommands.DisplayOverlays)
{
  ...
}
```

Note you are using enums to track a state. While there are other ways to use enums, I believe this is the most natural one.